# Storing python int as byte[] array for Hbase

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, hex, hbase

I have a Python int like 215666 and i need to store it in a byte array in hbase. The hex value of 215666 is 34A72 and i should have the following

```
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x34\x0A72
```

I've tried the following:

```
(215666).to_bytes(8, byteorder='big')
```

which gave me characters that are not HEX as such:

```
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00T>
```

This method seems to work for smaller numbers but then starts printing strange NON HEX values. I'm pretty sure hbase requires HEX values but all input on this is welcome.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(215666).to_bytes(8, byteorder='big').hex()
```

It doesn't have to be hex to be a valid `bytes`. If you want it in the hex format you are talking about, the `bytes` object has this `hex` method, that formats it as hex.

If you are interested, here is how I found `hex`.

1. I opened a python shell
2. I copied your line and assigned it to a variabled called `foo`:

```
foo = (215666).to_bytes(8, byteorder='big')
```

3. I looked at the type of `foo`: `type(foo)`
4. I looked at the methods/properties on `foo`: `dir(foo)`.
   I could see it was a `bytes` object and I saw the `hex` method so I just tried it.